# CSV data multiple level parsing Shell script

Tags: linux, bash, csv, delimiter, fileparsing

Hi I have a CSV data in following format

```
ColumnHeader1,ColumnHeader2,ColumnHeader3
valcol1p1,name=testapp1 environment=dev coldata=My_Test_Logs @$ 192.168.1.1 @$ r1 @$ r2 @$ POST API ,valcol3p1
valcol1p1,name=testapp2 environment=qa coldata=My_Test_Logs @$ 192.168.1.1 @$ r1 @$ r2 @$ GET API ,valcol3p1
```

[image: img sample data]
I

I need to extract the data in ColumnHeader2 column after My_Test_Logs and parse the data after the delimtter '@$'.So for each csv line I would get 4 values.
I need to concatenate them with the same delimiter value '@$' and place in CSV.

The output will be something like this

[image: Output]

Now i have solved it in parts.

Like to get the ColumnHeader2 column data

`awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $2}' Mytest.csv`

or to take only first x fields using multiple chars delimiter:

`awk -F"[@][$]" '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' Mytest1.csv`
where MyTest1 contains the output of extracted Columnheader2 data

But together the whole logic of extracting and then concatenating is giving some issues .Can someone please help here.I need a single script to work on my CSV and write the results in another csv rather using multiple csv or text outputs in between?

Comment: What should the output be for that sample data?

Comment: Something like this..Showed just one row but actually it would be all the rows from the csv
192.168.1.1 @$ r1 @$ r2 @$ GET API

Comment: Please, edit the sample output to the question for readability.

Comment: @JamesBrown done as suggested

Comment: You are on the right track, you just need to set the OFS variable also `awk -F ',| *@[$] *' -v OFS='@$' '{print $3,$4,$5}' sample.txt` (this combines both awk commands)

Comment: Perfect. @Sorin ...Any idea how I can get output with new columns as I have shown in my output. 
Now I get the output like this with your command
@$@$mnHeader3
192.168.1.1@$r1@$r2
192.168.1.1@$r1@$r2

What I want is something this

outCol1@$outCol2@$outcol3
192.168.1.1@$r1@$r2
192.168.1.1@$r1@$r2

Comment: @pythonNinja well I wasn't planning to write an answer. However, there you go https://stackoverflow.com/a/60636646/939457

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should met both your requirements:

```
awk -F',| *@[$] *' -v OFS='@$' -e 'NR==1 {print "outCol1","outCol2","outcol3"}; NR > 1 { print $3,$4,$5}' sample.txt

outCol1@$outCol2@$outcol3
192.168.1.1@$r1@$r2
192.168.1.1@$r1@$r2
```

- `-F',|@[$]' - field separator is a regular expression in awk, this will match both`,`and`@$`, and also trim the spaces around`@$`
- `-v OFS='@$'` - the default field separator for output is space, this will set it to '@$'
- `NR == 1 {print "outCol1","outCol2","outcol3"}` - for first line print the new header
- `NR > 1 { print $3,$4,$5}` - for the rest of the lines print fields $3,$4,$5

**Note:** this assumes that there are no `,` or `@$` escaped in the rest of the CSV, otherwise you should use a proper CSV parser.

Comment: Thanks @Sorin this worked.Great explanation as well

Answer (score 0):

Using awk to split at `My_Test_Logs`:

```
$ awk -F, '{print (split($2,a,/My_Test_Logs /)>1?a[2]:a[1])}' file
```

Output:

```
ColumnHeader2
@$ 192.168.1.1 @$ r1 @$ r2 @$ POST API 
@$ 192.168.1.1 @$ r1 @$ r2 @$ GET API
```

**Update:**

In the light of better presented expected output:

```
$ awk -F, '{print (split($2,a,/ /)>1?a[5] OFS a[6] OFS a[7] OFS a[8] OFS a[9] OFS a[10] OFS a[11] OFS a[12]:a[1])}' file
```

Output now:

```
ColumnHeader2
192.168.1.1 @$ r1 @$ r2 @$ POST API
192.168.1.1 @$ r1 @$ r2 @$ GET API
```

Comment: This as is is not working as delimtter is missing..I edited it like this :---- awk -F"[@][$]" '{print (split($2,a,/My_Test_Logs /)>1?a[2]:a[1])}' MyTest.csv

Comment: After that i am just getting first column as output and not all columns with again "@$" spacing...

Comment: 192.168.1.1 
 192.168.1.1

Comment: Thanks @james this is also a good alternate solution.The update makes things clear

Answer (score 0):

This will handle the CSV in a safe way unlike most bash tools.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import csv
csvr = csv.reader(open('your_file.csv'), delimiter = ",")

results = []
index=0
for row in csvr:
    if index == 0:
        index = index +1
        continue
    results.append(row[1].split('@$')[1:])

for row in results:
    print(",".join(row))
```

Output :

```
 192.168.1.1 , r1 , r2 , POST API 
 192.168.1.1 , r1 , r2 , GET API
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have a multiple character delimtter "@$"..TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string

Comment: @pythonNinja Using Python3 or Python 2?

Comment: I am using python3

Comment: @pythonNinja That it's weird. It should work perfectly fine. It did for me. Also, look at this : https://repl.it/repls/MetallicCloseKernel